# How to implement a completion handler for Firebase update before table.reloadData is called in a different class?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, completionhandler

Classes: ViewControllerTableViewCell and homepage ///the cell class is for cells on homepage

Problem: A button press triggers both 1) an IBAction that updated the firebase database (on ViewControllerTableViewCell) and 2) a model(on ViewControllerTableViewCell and homepage) that makes UI changes via table.reloadData.

The problem is the reloadData causes the wrong row to be recognized and updates in firebase for the wrong row. I checked this by removing reloadData and then the correct row is updated in firebase through the IBAction. Presumably this is because reloadData is executed before the database is done and then the row it returns are wrong. I am only having this problem with Xcode 13 btw.

class ViewControllerTableViewCell:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
 ...
 **ref.child("users").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updates)**
 }

@objc func likeButtonTapped() {
    // Calls the corresponding function of the delegate, which is set to the view controller.
    delegate?.didTapLikeButton(on: row, didLike: !model.didLike)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
    like?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

   func setup(with model: CellModel) {
   }
```

class homepage

```
 //in cellforRowAt {
 cell.setup(with: model)
 }

 // in viewdidLoad {
 setupmodels()
 }

 private func setupModels() {
 ....
 models.append(model)
 }

extension homepage: ViewControllerTableViewCellDelegate {
// Called from the cell's button action through the delegate property.
func didTapLikeButton(on row: Int, didLike: Bool) {
    // Updates the corresponding cell's model so that it will update the cell when
    // the table view reloads with the updated models.
    models[row].didLike = didLike
    **table.reloadData**
    print("BBBBBBBBB")
}
```

//Added after first answer

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? ViewControllerTableViewCell {
        let immy = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView
        let like = cell.viewWithTag(3) as? UIButton
        let person: Userx = people[indexPath.row]
        let text = person.Education
        
        cell.lblName.text = person.Education
        cell.lblName.text = text?.uppercased()
        
        let person5 = colorArray[indexPath.row]
        let person6 = colorArray1[indexPath.row]
        let person7 = colorArray2[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.lblName?.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.lblName?.backgroundColor = person5
        like?.backgroundColor = person6
        immy?.backgroundColor = person7
        cell.lblName.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
        cell.postID = self.people[indexPath.row].postID
        if let PhotoPosts = person.PhotoPosts {
            let url = URL(string: PhotoPosts)
            print(PhotoPosts, "sttdb")
            immy?.sd_setImage(with: url)
        }
        cell.row = indexPath.row
        // Assigns the delegate property to this view controller.
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.delegate2 = self
        let model = models[indexPath.row]
        let modell = modelss[indexPath.row]
        like?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        cell.setup(with: model)
        cell.setup1(with: modell)
        
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: why are you reloading the whole table when you can just reload that row? It will probably fix the issue as you will get the right `indexPath`

Comment: @ iOSArchitect.com How can you do that though? I didn't think of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments,

1. on `didTapLikeButton`, update changes to your current model.
2. Instead of `tableView.reloadData()`, Reload the `tableView row`

   ```
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
   ```

I am considering you have only 1 section in tableView, if not then get the section or the `indexPath` and pass it in the above code.

Comment: I tried that and before I tried: let rowNumber: Int = 2
let sectionNumber: Int = 0
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: rowNumber, section: sectionNumber)
self.table.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
It seems to work logically, only problem is the UI updates only if I scroll the row offscreen and then onscreen again

Comment: @florida27 In `cellForRowAt` make sure you write if else condition to set image or Like/Dislike label. IF and ELSE, both should be there in cellForRowAt code.

Comment: If confused, share the `cellForRowAt` code in the question and I will guide.

Comment: Thanks. Where in `cellForRowAt` would you add that else if? I have now added my `cellForRowAt` in the question.

Comment: so I have kind of gotten it to work without changing anything at `cellForRowAt`. I am not sure why it didn't work on Friday. The issue I had is it animates all other elements in the row (there are 3 tags in the row - only the right one should reload). This problem didn't happen when I simply used `table. reloadData()`. I did, however, manage to fix it by using `reconfigureRows` in stead of `reloadRows`, but this function only works on iOS 15. Any idea how to get reloadRows to only animate the 3rd tag in the row, so that my solution works on earlier iOS versions too?